# I get null value in spring controller when I user angular to post data

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I use Angularjs to post data to spring controller.

like this.

```
var user ={
    "userID" : "1",
    "username" : "hello",
    "password" : "123456"
};
console.log(user);
var response = $http.post("/login/signup",user);
response.success(function (data) {
    alert("success");
    alert(data);
});
response.error(function (data) {
    alert("error");
    alert(data);
});
```

My model

```
public class User {
    private long userID;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(long userID, String username, String password) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And My controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signUp(User user){
        String username = user.getUsername();// NULL!!
        System.out.println(username);
        return "login";
    }

}
```

I get null user like this.

If I add `@RequestBody` to my controller.I even could not get into the controller and get an exception.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String signUp(@RequestBody User user){
        String username = user.getUsername();
        System.out.println(username);
        return "login";
    }
```

exception

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

Comment: Can you check what is the `Content-Type` when you post your request?

Comment: Content-Type:application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set `Content-Type: application/json` in your request header when you are posting your data to server.

Also use:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Insted of:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
```

**EDIT**

Sometimes (I'm not sure when), `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` does not get registered with spring context which is responsible for converting request params to model bean. If it is not registered, registering it manually may resolve the issue.

Comment: Well, I used your code snippet and ran it in my local environment without any problem. I was able to get `username`. What response code you get, might tell something about the issue.

Comment: http 415,The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Comment: Turning on `DEBUG` level log for `org.springframework.web` may give you the exact reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109041/discussion-between-sudhir-singh-and-threezj).

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your model you should have

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
...
}
```

and not

```
public class User {
    private long userID;
    private String username;
    private String password;

...
}
```

because you post a json like this

```
 {
       "id" : "1",
       "username" : "hello",
       "password" : "123456"                        
}
```

and not

```
{
       "userID" : "1",
       "username" : "hello",
       "password" : "123456"                        
}
```

then in your controller should have

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String signUp(@RequestBoby User user){
        String username = user.getUsername();
        System.out.println(username);
        return "login";
    }

}
```

remember that in this case spring didn't change the page for you and in my opinion a better choice is use `@RestController` and `ResponseEntity` as result of your method for a fine grain control over the response like below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity signUp(@RequestBoby User user){
        String username = user.getUsername();
        System.out.println(username);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

I hope that this can help you

Comment: it is very strange many times I woks in this way and for me work probabliy more detail about the error can help as to help you to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

I finally to solve this problem by add `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` bean.

first add dependency in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

second,add Bean definition in your config.

```
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return jsonConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(jsonConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
```